# I am trying to get one tab to open when page loads using JS

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to get a tab to open when the page loads, it doesn't open until I click on the tab

I have searched through the code and cant find it, it was working yesterday but I have made multiple changes to the file and have little experience using JS.

```
<div class="input-res">    
        <input readonly id="original" type="text" value="Original Package Price" />
        <input readonly id="discount" type="text" value="Discount" />
        <input readonly id="totals" type="text" value="Total Package Price" />
    </div>
    <h4 id="selectbelow"> Please Select Items From The Table Below </h4>
    <div class="tab">
      <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Sofas')">Sofas</button>
      <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Armchairs')">Armchairs</button>
      <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Mattresses')">Mattresses</button>
    </div>

    <div id="Sofas" class="tabcontent">
          <table>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td><input class="checkproduct" name="product1" type="checkbox" value="1000" /> Sofa 1 €1000</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input class="checkproduct" name="product1" type="checkbox" value="100" /> Sofa 2 €100</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>

    <div id="Armchairs" class="tabcontent">
          <table style="display:block">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td><input class="checkproduct" name="product1" type="checkbox" value="400" /> Armchair 1 €400</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input class="checkproduct" name="product1" type="checkbox" value="200" /> Armchair 2 €200</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>

    <div id="Mattresses" class="tabcontent">
          <table style="display:block">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td><input class="checkproduct" name="product1" type="checkbox" value="400" /> Mattress 1 €400</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input class="checkproduct" name="product1" type="checkbox" value="200" /> Mattress 2 €200</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>

<script>
    function openCity(evt, cityName) {
      var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
      tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
      for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
        tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
      }
      tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
      for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
        tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
      }
      document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
      evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
    }
</script>
<script language="javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript">
      $(document).ready(function() {

          var amount = 0;
          var totalBefore = 0 ;
             var totalAmount = 0;
             var discount = 0;
             $('.checkproduct').click(function(){
                 amount=0;
                 totalAmount =0;
                 discount = 0;
                 totalBefore =0;
                    $('.checkproduct').each(function() {
                        debugger;
                            if($(this).attr('checked')){
                                amount=parseFloat($(this).val())
                                totalBefore +=amount; 
                                if(totalBefore>=1800){
                                    totalAmount = totalBefore -(totalBefore*0.1);
                                    discount = totalBefore*0.1;
                                }
                                else if(totalBefore>=2000){
                                    totalAmount = totalBefore -(totalBefore*0.15);
                                    discount = discount*0.15;
                                }
                                else{
                                    totalAmount = totalBefore ;
                                }
                            }
                        });
                        $('#original').val("Original Package Price            €" +totalBefore );
                        $('#discount').val("Discount                     €" +discount    );
                        $('#totals')  .val("Total Package Price  €" +totalAmount );
             });
      });

    if (totals >= 1000 && productCost < 1600)
    {
        discount = 0.9;
    }
</script>
```

Above is just a snippet of the code, all I am trying to do is just get the tab to be open 
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `if (totals >= 1000 && productCost < 1600)
    {
        discount = 0.9;
    }` looks out of place

Comment: So where do you trigger it to open up the tag on page load

Comment: @epascarello its for calculating the discounts above the top div, I didn't include that code as it is not relevant to the question

Comment: @epascarello I will edit the code above and link the full html so you can see